# Kendo UI editor: undo not working for backspace?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using the Kendo UI Editor with Angular. I added an editor button that executes an undo, using the exec('undo') function outlined here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor/methods/exec

This works great for everything except backspaces/deletes. It seems that these aren't captured in the undoRedoStack. Is there a configuration change that I can make so that the undoRedoStack will start capturing these, and exec('undo') would start working for backspaces/deletes?

Comment: This sounds like a bug and you should report bug to Progress directly.